# Are there any advantages of having Ubuntu on usb?

Tags: usb

I'm new to Linux and programming and I'm interested in downloading Ubuntu on my computer but i was wondering if there are any advantages of having it on a usb instead of installing it on my computer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I have flagged your question as "too broad". Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/787211/edit) your question and try to narrow down what you want to now about Ubuntu on a USB stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one obvious advantage of having an ubuntu installation on a portable usb-device is that is is .... **portable**.

Most other issues might come out as disadvantages - speed might be 1 example.

I agree with @MadMike that the question is somehow not perfect for the AskUbuntu-format .... would be better to discuss such questions in a forum or chat.

Comment: Also: a live USB lets you try out Ubuntu without installing it to your computer. You can click "Try Ubuntu" when it boots up.

Comment: Using Virtual Machines technology might be as well a good way to try & explore operating systems if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new to AskUbuntu so sorry for the broad question but thanks anyway.